# Why is form values not being inserted into database

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please show me where my code is incorrect for adding form values into a coordinate table? I let user enter number of coordinates to enter (that produces the text boxes on this page) before this page and then the coordinate values should be entered and populated to the database. I keep getting array to string conversion error but haven't been able to fix it.

How would values be inserted if the number of boxes can change? What if user only enters 4 which generates 4 rows of three coordinates each (x, y, z)? This is where i don't understand. I am able to get values to table if using only static form values.

i am beginner but learning slowly and gradually and am thankful for positive and constructive answers.

```
<head>
      <title>Add Coordinate to Database</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <?php
        if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbname = 'your_db_name';
        $dbuser = 'John';
        $dbpass = 'johns##password';

        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser,  
        $dbpass);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO coordTable (x, y, z) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['textx']);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['texty']); //what is difference between bindParam/bindValue

$stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['textz']);
$stmt->execute();
            }

            if(! get_coordinates() ) {
               $textx = filter_input($_POST['textx']);
               $texty = filter_input($_POST['texty']);
               $textz = filter_input($_POST['textz']);
            }else {
               $textx = $_POST['textx'];
               $texty = $_POST['texty'];
               $textz = $_POST['textz'];
            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO coordTable". "(x, y, z) 
               ) ". "VALUES('$textx','$texty',$textz)";

                           ?>

            <form method="post" action="output_process.php">

            <?php for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $num_boxes; $counter++) { ?>

            (x<?php echo $counter; ?>:<input name="textx[]<?php echo $counter; ?>" type="text" value="">,
            y<?php echo $counter; ?>: <input name="texty[]<?php echo $counter; ?>" type="text" value"">,
            z<?php echo $counter; ?>: <input name="textz[]<?php echo $counter; ?>" type="text" value"">)<br><br>

            <?php } ?>

            <input name="button2" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

Comment: Saw `mysql_*` functions, stopped reading. http://php.net/mysql_query - READ AND UPDATE!

Comment: Any errors you are getting ?

Comment: Your form doesn't actually have any fields with `name="textX"`…

Comment: I am receiving error "array as string". What is interesting is the expectation the manual/book I'm reading practicing doesn't include every bit of information for solving this problem so I go to web and see that examples on tutorial sites are using old methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other authors says, the mysql_ functions is outdated and does not work in PHP 7, you should choose something different. In addition, you did not sanitize the POST variables and malicious users can do anything with your database.

Here is the replacement with modern PDO:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'your_db_name';
    $dbuser = 'John';
    $dbpass = 'johns##password';

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO coordTable (x, y, z) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['textx']); $i++) {
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['textx'][$i]);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['texty'][$i]);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['textz'][$i]);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="output_process.php">

    <?php for ($counter = 1; $counter <= 5; $counter++): ?>

    (x<?= $counter ?>: <input name="textx[]" type="text" value="<?= $counter ?>">,
    y<?= $counter ?>: <input name="texty[]" type="text" value"<?= $counter ?>">,
    z<?= $counter ?>: <input name="textz[]" type="text" value"<?= $counter ?>">)<br><br>

    <?php endfor ?>

    <input name="button2" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is method book is teaching me, however it doesn't cover how to solve taking data from form fields if you see my input names textx[ ] fields and inserting into table. As for PDO that is what I've been using but decided to follow tutorial site example to possibly solve my problem. Guess I chose wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see now, you are trying to handle the variables array! Please check updated version.

Comment: I don't quite understand the (?, ?, ?) or the bindParam. I haven't used  that attribute yet but have used bindValue. Could you explain to me in easy terms difference? Thanks

Comment: bindParam escapes the variable and insert it in the SQL query where the "?" placed. It will be even faster in our case (when we need to run similar query several times).
bindParam could use named placeholders or question mark. I hope the documentation will make it more clear for you:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 0):

You have your query string as shown below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO coordTable". "(x, y, z) 
               ) ". "VALUES('$textX','$textY',$textZ)";
```

Whereas query string should be as shown below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO coordTable". "(x, y, z) 
               ) ". "VALUES('$textX','$textY','$textZ')";
```

Comment: What's the difference between those two statements?

Comment: @Quentin the `''` around `$textZ`.